Find $∡$ in a right triangle $ABC$ below
In a right triangle $ABC$ (∡−90°). Draw the cevian $AD$ and extend it to point $E$ such that $∡⁢⁢=53^$.
Calculate ∡ . If: CD = 2BE and ∡⁢⁢=2∡⁢⁢.
(Answer: $53^o$ )
I try

$ \angle C = 90^o -3\theta$
$\angle BDA = 90^o -\theta \implies \angle CDA = 90^o +\theta$
$\angle BDE = 180^o -(90^o -\theta) = 90^o +\theta$
$ \angle ADB = 180^o - (90^o +\theta) = 90^o -\theta$
$\angle EBD = 180^o - 53^o -(90^o +\theta) = 37^o -\theta$

This is a contradiction: $\angle BDE = 90^o +\theta $,  $ \angle EDB = 90^o -\theta$

@AdamDougall  Typing error.. The correct one is $ADB$.. I've already corrected it.

Since $\triangle ABC$ is right-angled, then the midpoint of $AC$, call it $O$, is the center of the circumscribed circle, with radius $r$, of $\triangle ABC$. Also, let
$$\vert CD\rvert = 2x$$
Next, consider the point $E'$ on the extension of $AD$. Have the perpendicular line from $B$ meets $AD$ at $F$. Thus, as $E'$ moves further down away from $D$, then $\lvert FE'\rvert$ is strictly increasing so, by the Pythagorean theorem, then $\lvert BE'\rvert$ will also be strictly increasing. As such, if we can show that with a particular $E'$ that $\lvert BE'\rvert = x$, then this would prove that $E = E'$.
In particular, have $E'$ be on the circumference of the circle, along with $AE'$, $OB$, $OE'$ and $E'C$ added to your diagram, as shown below:

Since $\angle BAE'$ and $\angle BCE'$ both subtend $BE'$, then $\measuredangle BAE' = \measuredangle BCE' = \theta$, as shown. As $E'$ is on the circumference, with $AC$ being the diameter, then $\measuredangle AE'C = 90^{\circ}$. Thus, considering $\triangle CE'D$, we have
$$\cos\theta = \frac{\lvert CE' \rvert}{\lvert CD\rvert} = \frac{\lvert CE' \rvert}{2x} \;\;\to\;\ \lvert CE' \rvert = 2x\cos\theta$$
Next, with $\triangle CE'A$, we get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sin(2\theta) & = \frac{\lvert CE'\rvert}{\lvert AC\rvert} \\
2\sin\theta\cos\theta & = \frac{2x\cos\theta}{2r} \\
2\sin\theta & = \frac{x}{r} \\
x & = 2r\sin\theta
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
By the Inscribed angle theorem, since $\measuredangle BAE' = \theta$, then $\measuredangle BOE' = 2\theta$, as shown. This means $\triangle BOE'$ is isosceles, so the perpendicular bisector of $BE'$ is also the angle bisector of $\angle BOE'$. Thus, half of $\lvert BE'\rvert$ is $r\sin\theta$, i.e.,
$$\lvert BE' \rvert = 2r\sin\theta = x$$
Thus, as explained initially, this shows that $E = E'$.
Since $\angle ACB$ and $\angle AE'B$ are both subtended from $AB$, we then have
$$\measuredangle ACB = \measuredangle AE'B = \measuredangle AEB$$
This is true for any acute angle. With $\measuredangle AEB = 53^{\circ}$ for this particular problem, then $\measuredangle ACB = 53^{\circ}$ as well.

You've made a great start. For simpler algebra, let
$$\lvert BE\rvert = x, \;\; \lvert CD\rvert = 2x$$
As you've determined, with $\measuredangle BDE = 90^{\circ} + \theta$,  then using the formulas from List of trigonometric identities of
$$\sin(90^{\circ} + \theta) = \sin(90^{\circ} - \theta) = \cos\theta, \;\; \sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$$
and the Law of sines, we get from $\triangle BDE$ that
$$\frac{\lvert BD\rvert}{\sin(53^{\circ})} = \frac{\lvert BE\rvert}{\sin(90^{\circ} + \theta)} \;\;\to\;\; \lvert BD\rvert = \frac{x\sin(53^{\circ})}{\cos\theta}$$
Next, since $\triangle ABD$ is a right-angled triangle, we have
$$\sin\theta=\frac{\lvert BD \rvert}{\lvert AD \rvert} \;\;\to\;\; \lvert AD \rvert = \frac{\lvert BD \rvert}{\sin\theta} = \frac{x\sin(53^{\circ})}{\sin\theta\cos\theta} = \frac{2x\sin(53^{\circ})}{\sin(2\theta)}$$
Using the law of sines with $\triangle ACD$ gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lvert CD\rvert}{\sin(2\theta)} & = \frac{\lvert AD\rvert}{\sin(∡C)} \\
\frac{2x}{\sin(2\theta)} & = \frac{\frac{2x\sin(53^{\circ})}{\sin(2\theta)}}{\sin(\measuredangle C)} \\
1 & = \frac{\sin(53^{\circ})}{\sin(\measuredangle C)} \\
\sin(\measuredangle C) & = \sin(53^{\circ})
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Since $0 \lt \measuredangle C \lt 90^{\circ}$, this finally means that
$$\measuredangle C = 53^{\circ}$$

Note the calculations above show that, in general,
$$\measuredangle ACB = \measuredangle AEB$$
i.e., $53^{\circ}$ can be replaced by any acute angle. Since these angles are the same and are both subtended from $AB$, then $ABEC$ forms a cyclic quadrilateral. As such, if $O$ is the midpoint of $AC$, then $\triangle ABC$ being right-angled means $O$ will also be the center of the triangle's circumcircle, so we therefore have
$$\lvert BO \rvert = \lvert EO \rvert = \lvert AO \rvert = \lvert OC \rvert$$
My other answer shows how to do basically the reverse of this one, i.e., with $E$ being on the circumcircle's circumference, then $\lvert CD\rvert = 2\lvert BE\rvert$ and, thus, $\measuredangle ACB = \measuredangle AEB$.

If we mark the circumcenter of triangle $ABC$ and connect $CE$ we can already guarantee that $E$ belongs to the circumference since $\angle A$ and $\angle BCE$ are submitted by the same arc $BE$. Therefore $\angle ACB = \angle AEB = 53^o $. Is this way of solving wrong?

@petaarantes Unfortunately, you would need to somehow show that $E$ is on the circumference due to the condition that $\lvert CD\rvert=2\lvert BE\rvert$. I can show that as a result of my calculations, but I'm unsure of how to do it in reverse.

Understood..thnks

@petaarantes FYI, in the answer that I just posted, I've used a relatively simple method to show the reverse, i.e., with $E$ on the circumference, then $\lvert CD\rvert = 2\lvert BE\rvert$. Note this uses just several properties of circles, cyclic quadrilaterals, and trig ratios, i.e., no law of sines or anything else like that. As such, you may consider it to be more "geometric" in nature than this one. Regarding "elegance", I consider both of these $2$ answers to be roughly the same, but perhaps you feel differently.

thanks for explanation


In figure AF is the bisector of angle DAC. we have:
$\angle AFB=\angle BCA+ \frac 13 \angle BAC$
Also angle BCE is angle BCG and is opposite to the arc DG of circle L and is equal to angle DAG which is one third of angle BAC, so we have:
$\angle ECA=\angle BCA+(\angle BCE=\angle BCG=\angle DAG= \frac 13 \angle BAC)$
SO:
$\angle ECA=\angle AFB$
Also:
$\angle BAF=\angle EAC=\frac 23 \angle BAC$
That is triangles ABF and AEC are similar which results in $\angle AEC=90^o$ wich in tern means E is on the circumcircle triangle ABC and $\angle BCA=\angle BEA=53^o$ because they are both opposite to Arc AB.

Thanks for help

@sirous How did you obtain $\angle BCE = \frac13 \angle BAC$ ? Because that is pretty much all we need.

@Euclid, because $\angle BCE=\angle BAE=\frac 13 \angle BAC$. I edited the answer.

How do we even know $\angle BCE = \angle BAE$ ? That equality is just assuming that $ABCE$ is cyclic, but $ABCE$ being cyclic is precisely what we want to prove!

@Euclid,         Because they are both opposite to arc BE.

We do not know whether $ABCE$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Could you please explain how you obtained that?

@Euclid, Thank you very much for your remark. In fact angle BCE is angle BCG and is opposite to the arc DG of circle L and is equal to angle DAG which is one third of angle BAC.

The same issue persists. We do not know whether points $A,D,G,C$ are cyclic. Could you please explain how you obtained that these points are cyclic?

@sirous Note that $E$ is on the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$ if and only if $\lvert CD\rvert=2\lvert BE\rvert$. In particular, if the multiplier was different from $2$, e.g., $1.9$ or $2.1$, then $E$ would not be on the circumcircle. However, I don't see anything in your answer that uses this information, even indirectly. Let me know if there's something I'm missing that does use, or show, this. Otherwise, please add an indication, ideally explicit, in your answer which either uses that equation, or proves the equation is true.

ADGC are definitely cyclic because G is where the bisector of angle ADC meets perpendicular bisector of DC on the circumcircle of triangle ADC.
